# Use Entity Framework Core with ThreadPool without reaching maximum SQL Server connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, entity-framework-core, threadpool

I try to insert a big load of data to my SQL Server with out reaching the maximum connection.

I already tried to max the pool size in my connection string like this:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Echo;Max Pool Size=5000;Pooling=True;");
```

Is it possible to use one connection for each thread?

Here is my code

```
    public static void GenerateMeridien()
    {
        List<Parallele> paralleleList = null;

        using (var context = new EchoContext())
        {
            paralleleList = context.Paralleles.ToList();
        }

        foreach (Parallele parallele in paralleleList)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MeridienTaskCallback), parallele);
        }
    }

    private static void MeridienTaskCallback(object paralleleObj)
    {
        Parallele parallele = (Parallele)paralleleObj;

        // The context always reaches maximum connection because the garbage collector is not fast enough
        using (var context = new EchoContext())
        {
            List<Square> squareList = SquareLogic.GenerateSquare(parallele);
            context.Squares.AddRange(squareList);

            context.SaveChanges();
            Console.Write("*");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Proper use of `IDisposable` (usually through `using`) negates the "garbage collector not run". What connection exactly is (temporarily) leaking?

Comment: Please provide some numbers: how much data, how oftem etc.

Comment: The issue which @tymtam alludes to in his answer is that your code is trying to run in parallel ALL of the inserts all at the same time. The solution is to simply limit the number of workers at any one time.

Comment: As an aside, there is no reason for you to use multi-threading at all. If you switch to async/await, you would be able to run this 'single threaded/async/concurrent'.

Comment: Get proper BulkCopy library and insert everything in one batch.

Answer (score 1):

## Option A. Do work in parallel, save once

Do you have to save after each calculation? Can you do calculations in parallel and save after?

```
List<Parallele> paralleleList = null;

using (var context = new EchoContext())
{
    paralleleList = context.Paralleles.ToList();
}

List<Square> squares = DoAllWorkInParallel(paralleleList);

// Save once:
using (var context = new EchoContext())
{
    context.Squares.AddRange(squares);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

## Option B. Save all the time

I think you should use `Parallel.ForEach` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` or use `Task.WhenAll`.

#### Parallel.ForEach

For example:

```
public static async Task GenerateMeridien()
{
    List<Parallele> paralleleList = null;

    using (var context = new EchoContext())
    {
        paralleleList = context.Paralleles.ToList();
    }

    Parallel.ForEach(
        source: paralleleList,
        parallelOptions: new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = x},
        body: parallele => Work(parallele));

    
}

private static void Work(Parallele parallele)
{
    using (var context = new EchoContext())
    {
        List<Square> squareList = SquareLogic.GenerateSquare(parallele);
        context.Squares.AddRange(squareList);

        await context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

#### Task.WhenAll

```
public static async Task GenerateMeridien()
{
    List<Parallele> paralleleList = null;

    using (var context = new EchoContext())
    {
        paralleleList = context.Paralleles.ToList();
    }

    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (Parallele parallele in paralleleList)
    {
        tasks.Add(WorkAsync(parallele));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

private static async Task WorkAsync(Parallele parallele)
{
    using (var context = new EchoContext())
    {
        List<Square> squareList = SquareLogic.GenerateSquare(parallele);
        context.Squares.AddRange(squareList);

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```